# Puppeteer C#: Connecting to Running Chrome Instance

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I am currently running PuppeteerSharp v1.19.0 to launch a browser and scrape web pages. The need has come up to be able to connect to an existing chrome instance and automate tasks. How can I achieve this one PuppeteerSharp? Via the following, I'm able to launch Chrome instead of Chromium with PuppeteersSharp but I haven't found how I'm able to connect to an existing instance of Chrome. All help is appreciated.

```
using PuppeteerSharp;

new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
_browser = Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions { Headless = false, ExecutablePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 4):

First thing, you need to launch Chrome with remote debugging enabled.
If you launch Chrome, for instance, with the flag `--remote-debugging-port=2122`, you know that you will be able to connect to the browser using the `http://127.0.0.1:2122` URL.

Second, if you want to `connect` to an existing browser you need to call `ConnectAsync` instead of `LaunchAsync`.

Having all that. If would be a matter of doing something like this:

```js
var browser = await Puppeteer.ConnectAsync(new ConnectOptions
{
    BrowserURL = "http://127.0.0.1:2122"
}));
```

Comment: if I launch chrome on windows via `start chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222` and visit `http://localhost:9222`, I get a `this site cant be reached` error

Comment: @GregH Just go to `http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version`. Read [this article](https://medium.com/@jaredpotter1/connecting-puppeteer-to-existing-chrome-window-8a10828149e0)

Comment: i have the same problem. Could not connect to chrome